# c#-Unable to retrieve email using openpop.net

Tags: c#, authentication, smtp, gmail, pop3

I build an application to retreive email from gmail account. I can very well view email on my development PC, however when I run the setup on production PC(client PC), it gives error

> POP3 Server Authentication-The server did not accept user credentials.

I tried replacing port from 995 to 587 and 465, but same issue.
I also added `AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword`

My code for connection:

```
if (pop3Client.Connected)
                pop3Client.Disconnect();
            pop3Client.Connect(popServerTextBox.Text, int.Parse(portTextBox.Text), useSslCheckBox.Checked);
            //pop3Client.Authenticate(loginTextBox.Text, passwordTextBox.Text,AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);
            pop3Client.Authenticate(loginTextBox.Text, passwordTextBox.Text);
```

What am I missing  here.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the issue. It was gmail who was blocking connection, I just needed to add production PC on gmail and it worked.

Thanks